# Wordpress allow previews outside wordpress folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a file structure like

```
   example.com/mywordpress/  --contains WordPress
   example.com/custompreview.php --preview getter outside wordpress
```

I am using wp-load.php to load wordpres and using its contents. I am able to recive published posts with no problem, I even know how to make query for previews but when preview get parameters comes to the script outside the wordpress folder (custompreview.php) obviously the wp-load.php calls exit and shows only access error message.

**Example** is worth thousand words:

```
example.com/custompreview.php?preview=true&preview_id=64&preview_nonce=1f2477c5d2&post_format=standard
```

Shows only message `"You do not have permission to preview drafts"`

What is causing this? What is the wp-load.php checking for? How to fix this? :)

Comment: Where do you get that URL from? Are you logged in as a user?

Comment: I redirect urls from wp-themeed header to my custom page. I am logged in as admin. Note that if I dont redirect the preview works properly. It only doesnt work when I am resending the GET attributes to my wp-external script :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting this while logged in -

the session cookie may be limited to the `/mywordpress` folder.

Unless explicitly specified, the cookie will be valid in the subdirectory it was set in (and all children).

I'm not sure whether it is possible to change WP's session cookie behaviour, but it may help to put the PHP file inside `/mywordpress`.

Comment: It really seems that cookie check is the problem, so I will just copy it to session and then put it into my cookies.